# PickerView Custom in Swift programmatically

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to build a custom PickerView.

a) I would like to remove the two SelectionIndicator lines.
I have read that in the latest versions of iOS it is no longer possible to delete these two lines, but I would like to at least change their color to camouflage them.

b) I would like to give rounded corners to the purple background of the selected item.

I've written everything in the code, but it doesn't work.
[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCancel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnConfirmation: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lb: UILabel!
    
    var list = ["Madrid", "Sidney", "Toronto", "NewYork", "Oslo"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
        
        viewContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 40
        viewContainer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        viewContainer.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7647058824, green: 0.7647058824, blue: 0.7647058824, alpha: 1)
        viewContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        viewContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        
        btnCancel.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
        btnCancel.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: CGFloat(16))
        btnCancel.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btnCancel.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6829224825, green: 0.6091368198, blue: 0.9736139178, alpha: 1)
        btnCancel.layer.cornerRadius = btnCancel.frame.height/2.0
        btnCancel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapBtnCancel(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        btnConfirmation.setTitle("Confirm", for: .normal)
        btnConfirmation.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: CGFloat(16))
        btnConfirmation.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btnConfirmation.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6705882353, green: 0.6117647059, blue: 0.9490196078, alpha: 1)
        btnConfirmation.layer.cornerRadius = btnConfirmation.frame.height/2.0
        btnConfirmation.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapBtnConfirmation(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func tapBtnCancel(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
    @objc func tapBtnConfirmation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        lb.text = list[self.pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    }


}



extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }
   
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        
        let pickerLabel = UILabel()
        pickerLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6829224825, green: 0.6091368198, blue: 0.9736139178, alpha: 1)
        pickerLabel.text = list[row]
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 22)
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        
        pickerLabel.layer.cornerRadius = pickerLabel.frame.height/2.0
        pickerLabel.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9468494058, green: 0.9369241595, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        
        return pickerLabel
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Try adding a borderColor to your pickerLabel's layer to figure out what's going on. You might need to set it to clip the layer to its bounds.

Comment: Thanks i solved for the rounded corners. But how can I hide the two horizontal lines?